# Windows Phone 8 detected as mass storage

Tags: rhythmbox, mtp, mass-storage, windows-phone

From version 8 onwards Windows Phone supports MTP (media transfer protocol) to transfer audio and I thought I could use Rhythmbox to upload music onto my device.

Thing is Rhythmbox doesn't display the device under *Devices* pane (there's no *Device* pane for that matter).

I searched other questions here and tried out installing `mtp-tools`, `mtpfs` and also tried gMTP, which doesn't seem to detect the device as a portable player.

I see that the device's icon looks like a Camera in dash bar and when I see the address location, it shows `gphoto2://[usb:002,013]/`, which makes me doubt that it's detected as a camera or as a mass storage device. `/.gvfs/gphoto2 mount on usb%3A002,003` is where the actual mount is. What do I do to fix this?

I tried creating [.is_audio_player](http://www.m-phasis.de/2008/09/26/rhythmbox-and-usb-mass-storage-sync/) [too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158859/philips-gogear-detected-by-rhythmbox-but-not-banshee?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading this article:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/music/syncing-music-faq

"You can navigate to your phone's Music folder (or the Music folder on your phone's SD card, if it has one), and then drag files to it from your PC."

which to me makes it sound like you can (outside of rythmbox) open the Music folder on the device and copy files directly there.  The simple solution might be to just to open your PC's music folder, select all, and copy the music into the device's music folder.

Does that work for you?  This doesn't work at all with my WP7, but I was thinking of an upgrade to keep my trifecta going -- Ubuntu Dekstop, Android Tablet, Windows Phone :)  If that doesn't work I'm hoping there's good cloud storage.

Comment: Of course, directly copying music to the phone's music folder was my obvious first method. Didn't work out :(

Comment: With Windows Mobile devices, you could navigate onto them as if they were hard drives, but you had to have windows mobile device center (or activesync) installed.  I'll be that's the case with Windows 8.  Thanks.

Comment: But how do you install ActiveSync on Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't think you can. My guess is that it is too integrated with Windows to be something that would work with Wine. It would be quite a trick.  For now I'll be using a Virtual Machine with Windows running.

Comment: Something like that is what I do too; but http://sourceforge.net/projects/synce/ would be something worth trying out.